# laravel 4.1 scaffold generated code gives error :Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::all()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, scaffold

I am using scaffold command to generate code, but when i do scaffold for "event" everything go fines but when i try to load event controller in browser it shows following error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::all()

My event controller code is

```
class EventsController extends BaseController {
protected $event;

public function __construct(Event $event)
{
    $this->event = $event;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $events = $this->event->all();

    return View::make('events.index', compact('events'));
    }

}
```

I din't understand why it throw error because its auto generated code, and i do 3 scaffold before this one and they are working well . may be i cant put the name "**event**" or "**static**" while generating scaffold. because when i generate scaffold for "static" also it give some kind of error and when i scaffold "staticcontent" its work well.

**Note**

By scaffold i mean scaffold command

```
php artisan generate:scaffold event --fields="from:date, body:text"
```

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event class already exists so you'll have to change the name of your model to something else. Ran into this same issue before and was banging my head off the wall for hours.

Comment: thanks yes you are right  , the event class already exist, so now there are to way either change your model name or use namespace